# maintenance page when no healthy instances in target group

Tags: maintenance-mode, amazon-alb

Is there a way to serve a maintenance page in case there are no healthy instances in the associated target group in an amazon application load balancer?

I was thinking of a way to show a nice html maintenance page to my users if my instances whithin the associated target group are not healthy (i.e.: are returning 4xx, 5xx status codes)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it using ALB, but it should be doable using Route53.